# error loading keras model using DL4j: "nn.modelimport.keras.Hdf5Archive :Unexpected end-of-input within/between OBJECT entries"

Tags: keras, deep-learning, microservices, pom.xml, deeplearning4j

I am using DL model trained with keras and tensor flow (saved to h5 file). in a spring boot microservice also dockerized.

I need help to solve this error when I try to running a docker image with this spring boot service invoking keras model using dl4j library:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

The pom.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.autentia</groupId>
<artifactId>micro-service-spring-boot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>micro-service-spring-boot</name>
<description>Demo project microservice with Spring Boot and Docker</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.M3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <docker.image.prefix>curso</docker.image.prefix>
           <nd4j.version>1.0.0-beta2</nd4j.version>
            <dl4j.version>1.0.0-beta2</dl4j.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
  </dependency>  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>      
    <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>      
    <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta2</version>    
    </dependency>         
    <dependency>      
      <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>      
      <artifactId>deeplearning4j-modelimport</artifactId>      
      <version>1.0.0-beta2</version>    
    </dependency>                       
    <dependency>      
      <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>      
      <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-beta2</version>    
    </dependency>
    <dependency>      
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>      
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>      
      <version>9.4.9.v20180320</version>   
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>      
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>      
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>  
      <version>2.2.0</version>     
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
                <registryUrl>https://index.docker.io/v1/</registryUrl>
                <forceTags>true</forceTags>
                <imageTags>
                    <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
                </imageTags>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-image</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>push-image</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>push</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</imageName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And the code is:

```
package com.EjemplosEva;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModelImport;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork;
import org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray;
import org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j;
import org.nd4j.linalg.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.Hdf5Archive;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.*;

@RestController

public class GuestbookController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/micro-service")

  public String hello() throws Exception {
      // load the model
      final MultiLayerNetwork model;
            try {
                String simpleMlp = new ClassPathResource("modelLstm.h5").getFile().getPath();
                System.out.println("File opened\n");
                model = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(simpleMlp);
                System.out.println("Fichero imported\n");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
      return ("Hello world first step finished");
  }
```

}

I have checked it with several dl4j versions but the problem still happens.

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your screenshot:

1. It appears that it has problems with reading the actual h5 file
2. It can't cast a hashmap to a list

The second problem indicates that whatever it could read does not conform to what is expected. I guess you are using `tf.keras` and not the Standalone Keras Version, right?

Unfortunately, as of version 1.0.0-beta6, deeplearning4j does not support the import of models created with `tf.keras`.

Comment: yes, I am using tf.keras. And I have tried with differents dl4j versions with problems too. I can read this h5 file using flask without problems

Comment: Then, unfortunately, my last sentence does apply to your case: tf.keras import is not supported at the moment.

Comment: Finally I solved it using java 11 and beta6 dl4j. Thanks!